# Scrollable Scrollview with Listview inside in android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have such a complex views in a way that i include listview inside scrollview. What I would like to do is listview contains full screen and only scrollview is scrollable. I know it is not a good practice but I have to make this view. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed **very very bad** practice.. to the point that you can even no longer call it practice. But you don't have to do anything special to do that! By putting a `List` inside of `ScrollView` with the same `android:orientation` the `List` `height` or `width` will behave like `wrap_content` automatically and the `List` will `inflate` all of its **children** losing its scrolling behavior.

Just add this to your `ScrollView`:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

and this to your `ListView`:

```
android:height="wrap_content"
```

P.S: I recommend using list **header/footer** if you have to add extra views to your layout or moving your items to list as a **ListItem**. Both approach benefit from list behavior of recycling views and will improve your **Ram usage** and **Loading time**.

Happy Programming!

Comment: I know it is really bad practice. Cant be accepted. But I have got a project that is implemented this way. I want to modify the whole things, it takes me to change all the project structure. What I would like to do is to make scrollview is scrollable while listview is not, and i want the listview to fill the parents. Is it possible

Comment: Well I really suggest the workarounds that I mentioned in P.S. But if you insist you can try the code fragments I added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom implementation of `ListView`. It simply overrides the `.onMeasure()` method to wrap its children.

https://github.com/paolorotolo/ExpandableHeightListView/blob/master/library/app/src/main/java/com/github/paolorotolo/expandableheightlistview/ExpandableHeightListView.java

Answer (score 1):

Its able to make with NonScrollListView .

https://github.com/eugenkiss/chanobol/blob/master/src/main/java/anabolicandroids/chanobol/util/NonScrollListView.java

You can show your all item in scrollview . you just make your listview size wrap_content and use this view.

happy coding :)